# How to uninstall node

Tags: node.js, apache, gruntjs

I installed "Roots" theme for WordPress which comes with a "Grunt" build script which requires nodejs.

I deleted the theme via FTP but what's left is the theme folder along with a "node_modules" folder with what seems like thousands of files. Every time I delete the folder, it's like it recreates it with all of the files.

How can I uninstall nodejs/grunt?

The install process was to go to the theme's directory and use the command npm install then "grunt" and "grunt watch".

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Every `Node.js` package contains a `package.json` file which contains information about what all to install in the current folder.

So, if you don't want the node modules, just remove unwanted `packages` list from the `dependencies` section in your `package.json` and delete the `node_modules` folder.

If you want to use `grunt watch` command, you need `grunt` package with `grunt-contrib-watch` package and all these are in `node_modules`. If you delete these dependencies from `package.json` you can't use these commands any more.

More information about `package.json` can be found at : https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Hope this solves your issue.